# In the Game of the Goose, keep moving again and again if I keep landing on geese?

Tags: game-of-the-goose

In the Game of the Goose, if you land on a square with a goose, you may move the same amount of squares again. If that lands you on a square with a goose again, can you move yet again?

In theory, since squares with geese are 9 squares apart, if you're on go and throw 9, you keep going again and again until you've won. This can't happen on your first turn, since throwing ⚂ + ⚅ (3 + 6) takes you to square 26, while ⚃ + ⚄ (4 + 5) takes you all the way to square 53. But if you land on square 58 and die, you go back to the start, but then it's no longer your first turn.

Am I correct in assuming that throwing 9 *then*, wins you the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game of goose has many variants, including different square orderings, different rules for landing on certain squares and different numbers of dice.

The variant you describe (two dice, geese every 9 squares) is quite common, and the rule for rolling a nine on the first turn is as follows:

> If the roll is a 6 and 3, move directly to field 26; if the roll is a 4 and 5, advance all the way to 53.

Since you could only roll a nine and land on a goose when you are on the start square, you don't have the opportunity to land on multiple geese in one go from any other square on the board.

The rules quote was from this [goose page](http://www.recoveredscience.com/gooserules.htm). Interestingly this set of rules explicitly says moving to square 26 or 53 only applies on your first go. So if you find yourself back at the start, e.g. due to the death square, or somebody landing on you on their first go, then you can throw a nine and win the game.

Another site with two-dice goose rules is [here](http://www.gamepuzzles.com/goose.htm), and it features an image of the game board that shows a pair of dice on squares 26 and 53. This acts as a visual reminder of the rule. This rules page does not allow a throw of nine to ever win the game from the start square, as it associates the rule with the square:

> A lucky throw of 9 at the beginning of the spiral path advances a player to one of the fields with dice.

The game of goose has been played over many hundreds of years, and plenty of variation has been introduced during this time. Consequently the important thing is to pick a set of rules everyone's happy with before you start the game.

Comment: But you could go to square 58 and die, which takes you back to the start, but then it wouldn't be your first turn anymore.

Comment: @ATS Yes, I agree. The first set of rules I linked to say that you can do that, roll a nine and win; the second set of rules say that you can't, you just end up at 26 or 53.